# Finding volume using washer method

Tags: calculus, volume

I'm supposed to determine the volume of the region obtained  by revolving the region lying below the graph of the given function and above the $x$-axis about the specified axis. The problem I'm given is

> $y = x^2 + x + 1,\quad  y = 10,\quad  x \text{ in } [0, 2]$.

I drew it out. We are using the Washer method here. So big $R$ is $10$, little $r$ is $x^2+x+1$.

So now it's just a matter of plugging in the numbers and doing the integration.

$$\pi \int_0^2 (10)^2 - (x^2+x+1)^2\ dx,$$

Problem is, I get $\dfrac{858\pi}{5}$ but according to the book, the answer is $\dfrac{1574\pi}{15}$.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct formula is $$ \pi \int_0^2 \left(100- \left(10 -x^2-x-1\right)^2\right)\ dx.$$

Comment: Thanks. do you always square Big R first then combine  the original big R with little R?

Comment: @Kevin, the washer has two radii; outer radius $(R), $  and inner radius. the outer radius is from the axis of rotation to the tip of the area element. here it is $10.$ the inner radius ($r$) is from the axis of rotation to the top. her that is $10 - y = 10-(x^2 + x  + 1)$

Comment: Oh man. I get it now. Did my HW all wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinR., at least you found out before a test or a quiz on it.  it helps to draw a figure with the area element and axis rotation clearly marked. i make my students write out all of that.